# How to get the self-DOM object in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#subPanel").click(function() {
    $("#subPanel").removeClass('btn-success');// it works
    this.addClass('btn-default'); it didn't works.
```

I would like to get self-dom object(in this case `$("#subPanel")` itself)  from inside the call back.

It might be easy problem, so I try to googled around.
However I couldn't get straight answer.
could you help me ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect `this` and you will see it's not a jquery object but a DOM element which does not have an addClass method. Try:

```
$("#subPanel").click(function() {
    $("#subPanel").removeClass('btn-success');// it works
    $(this).addClass('btn-default')
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/14s0h3dr/

Comment: @down-voter explanation please?

Comment: Thanks, it is very neat solution and answer.